# Searching for an old laptop to learn linux

Tags: linux, laptop, programming

I have years of experience in programming algorithms and compiling statistics.

Now I would like to develop my skills and immerse myself in the world of Linux in order to get more involved with the computer itself.

That's why I wanted to get an old laptop at a reasonable price to learn Linux. A friend of mine made the following suggestions:

- Lenovo Thinkpad X220
- Macbook Pro 13 mid 2014 Retina

What would you suggest? Preferably cheap laptops that I can work on myself in case of problems so that I can also learn from them and that I can also work with them. It should also be possible to program.

Comment: Old thinkpads are very robust and easy to get replacement parts for, and official service manual for how to exchange things can be found. The mbp is probably the nicer laptop, performance wise. This is your decision to make, and has nothing to do with Linux

Comment: Yes, I know that it has nothing to do with Linux. But I was curious if you people also have suggestion for old laptops to learn Linux (performance wise and to handle it in the future) and also gain experience in replacing components, upgrading, etc.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because shopping recommendations are off-topic here.

Comment: I switched to the forum intentionally to ask this question here.

Comment: @PaiThon you're generally extremely welcome here! But this simply isn't the right place to ask, and the fact that we found this place via search engines is because this places adheres to its rules to what is on- and what is off-topic somewhat strictly, making the content that stays rather high quality. So, I'm afraid you're not quite right to ask this here; we're not a general discussion forum, but a very specific questions-and-answers site for things particularly about Unix/Linux, no changing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not answering the hardware question because that is indeed off-topic, but suggest an alternative approach: use a virtual machine.

You should be aware that your goal as stated ("Learning Linux") is very unspecific. What exactly do you want to learn?

- Sysadmin proficiency (bash commands etc.)?
- Networking?
- Kernel hacking?
- Becoming familiar with one of the Linux desktop environments?
- Compiling and packaging applications etc.?

Many of these (except for kernel hacking, which is probably not your main goal given your background) can be done well on a virtual machine. In fact, many of the Linux servers running on the internet and in the various clouds are virtual machines, so learning on a VM is pretty close to what you'd actually need for this kind of usage.

If you're using a sufficiently powerful machine already (any somewhat recent laptop or desktop machine should do), installing a VM environment and trying out various distributions should be the quickest route to get some experience. On Windows, you could even use WSL to get a fairly usable environment quickly, although this might be somewhat lacking in the networking realism.